# Compare date and classify it into new columns using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm quite new with SQL.

I have a table `Order` dated from 22/5/2020 till 22/9/2020 that looks like this:

```
order_number    order_completed_date    order_delivered_date    customer_id   stock_location_id
R739630059         21/8/2020 13:13         21/8/2020 14:52         80706            823
R396187630         19/8/2020 12:58         19/8/2020 14:00         80706            823
R873840421         27/5/2020 0:13          27/5/2020 12:22         80706            823
R169280426         27/5/2020 10:15         27/5/2020 12:19         681843           382
R100113224         20/9/2020 15:07         22/9/2020 12:11         152769           1048
R528017703         20/9/2020 18:05         21/9/2020 10:26         557935           382
R482536784         20/9/2020 17:42         21/9/2020 19:56         1183892          828
```

I want to compare the `order_completed_date` for every `customer_id` and have a result that looks like this:

```
customer_id first_order stock_location_id   second_order    stock_location_id   third_order stock_location_id
   80706   27/5/2020 0:13     823          19/8/2020 12:58          823        21/8/2020 13:13     823
   681843  27/5/2020 10:15    382               
   152769  20/9/2020 15:07    1048              
   557935  20/9/2020 18:05    382               
   1183892 20/9/2020 17:42    828
```

The `first_order` column will have all the oldest order for every customer and the latest will go into the `second_order` column and so on depending on the date. I would like some suggestion on how I can do this.

Comment: Do you have the requirement to support an arbitrary (and possibly unknown) number of orders?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nope...if possible..I would like to list them all...because I will extract the data for certain period only like a month up to 6 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below way - using `conditional aggregation`

```
select customer_id, 
       max(case when rn=1 then order_completed_date end) as first_order,
       max(case when rn=1 then stock_location_id end) as f_stock_location_id,
       max(case when rn=2 then order_completed_date end) as second_order,
       max(case when rn=2 then stock_location_id end) as s_stock_location_id,
       max(case when rn=3 then order_completed_date end) as third_order,
       max(case when rn=3 then stock_location_id end) as t_stock_location_id
from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by order_completed_date) as rn
from T
)A group by customer_id
```

Comment: sorry...what is A?

Comment: it's an alias for the subquery- when you write a subquery you've name it @NurAtiqah

Comment: alright...noted...so...if in the data, one customer has more than 3 orders...how can I improve the code? hardcoded like you do?

Comment: @NurAtiqah, I am not sure if postgres support pivot or not? you can search that - I guess that could be a better option

Comment: postgres does support pivot...thanks...will try and explore more...as of now...your answer is good enough

Comment: @NurAtiqah, if it helped u please mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to aggregate the dates and ids into arrays:

```
select customer_id, 
       completed_dates[1] as first_order,
       location_ids[1]    as first_stock_location_id,
       completed_dates[2] as second_order,
       location_ids[2]    as second_stock_location_id,
       completed_dates[3] as third_order,
       location_ids[3]    as third_stock_location_id
from (
  select customer_id, 
         array_agg(order_completed_date order by order_completed_date) as completed_dates,
         array_agg(stock_location_id  order by order_completed_date) as location_ids
  from the_table
  group by customer_id
) A
```